# MySQL store table on separate disk

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5 with MyISAM on my system. What happens is that one large table is populated each day and I want this table to reside on a separate (fast) disk, the day it is created and populated. The next day I would like to move it to the slower disk, without interrupting access to the database of course. The question is: is this something that can be done with MySQL and MyISAM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK multiple data directories are not supported in mysql till now. 
You have several other options, here:

- if you're running MySQL on Linux, you could symlink the table (the .myd file) into your normal data directory from some other mountpoint, e.g. the fast storage
- If the table is not very big, you could store it with the "memory" table type and spent your application some code which takes care of syncing.
- you could set up multiple mysql instances on your machine with different data-directories.
- Switch over to InnoDB and make use of *innodb_data_file_path*

Comment: although just having the data file path changed will not help much - the binary log would reside on a fast disk as well (ideally on a disk which is *not* holding the data files as well)

Comment: These could be valid solutions except for using memory engine, because the table is pretty big (30 million rows).
The question is: how you can move the table from disk to disk without affecting the db's availability?

Comment: Do you have a timestamp field in the table? Then you could do something like a delta transfer of the table (create a new table with select * from oldtable where timestamp < today, when finished, transfer only new values from today, rename oldtable and newtable)